# Pandas. Splitting Data frame content continuously and evenly across multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

As a simple example, suppose I have the following data frame in pandas

```
the_content = {"Name" : ["John", "Kathy", "Kurtis", "Sharon"], 
              "Hobbies" : ["Fishing", "Sewing", "Skiing", "Biking"]}
```

When I then create a data frame:

```
panda_table = pd.DataFrame(the_content)
```

And then convert it into an html table:

```
html_panda_table = panda_table.to_html()
```

The result consists of four data rows and two columns. Something like

```
    Names    Hobbies
0   John     Fishing
1   Kathy    Sewing
2   Kurtis   Skiing
3   Sharon   Biking
```

However, I would like to split the same content across repeating rows, evenly. The purpose of this becomes more obvious if there are lots of data. In this case, I would want to set a value, say 4 columns. Then there would be only one data row and 8 columns.

```
   Names   Hobbies   Names     Hobbies   Names   Hobbies    Names   Hobbies
0  John    Fishing 1 Kathy     Sewing  2 Kurtis  Skiing  3 Sharon  Biking
```

And if there were more than 4 data points, such as 6 data points, or 50 data points, then the rows would stack.

How can I set the number of columns and then have the data distribute evenly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate in the rows of your original dataframe in order to build tiny dataframes and save them in a list. Finally using [`pd.concat(axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) you can concat them to get the expected result.

**Edit:** According your comment, I have updated the code to create a new row in the dataframe based on `max_size_row` variable. The idea here is slicing our `df_list` in chunks according to the length of the row, then create the full row using [`pd.concat(axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and store it in `df_list_row`. When We have all rows in `df_list_row`, We make [`pd.concat(axis=0)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) (this is the default value). Maybe there are other best approaches, but I think this is a good answer.

```
import numpy as np

df_list = []
df_list_row = []
start = 0
max_size_row = end = 4 

for row in panda_table.to_numpy():
  df_list.append(pd.DataFrame(data=[row], columns=panda_table.columns))

while start < len(df_list):
  df_row = df_list[start:end]
  if len(df_row) < max_size_row:
    df_row += [pd.DataFrame(data=[[np.nan, np.nan]], columns=panda_table.columns)]*(max_size_row - len(df_row))
  df_list_row.append(pd.concat(df_row, axis=1))
  start += max_size_row
  end += max_size_row

df = pd.concat(df_list_row).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output with `max_size_row = 2`**:

| Name | Hobbies | Name | Hobbies |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Fishing | Kathy | Sewing |
| Kurtis | Skiing | Sharon | Biking |
| Carlos | Writing | NaN | NaN |

**Output with `max_size_row = 3`**:

| Name | Hobbies | Name | Hobbies | Name | Hobbies |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Fishing | Kathy | Sewing | Kurtis | Skiing |
| Sharon | Biking | Carlos | Writing | NaN | NaN |

**Output with `max_size_row = 4`**:

| Name | Hobbies | Name | Hobbies | Name | Hobbies | Name | Hobbies |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Fishing | Kathy | Sewing | Kurtis | Skiing | Sharon | Biking |
| Carlos | Writing | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |

Comment: Thanks! However, if I add a 5th item, I would want it to create another row below John. In this solution, it will keep one row and add a 5th column instead of a new row. How can that be done?
After every 4th element, the next element should start a new row.

Comment: @geekygeek I have updated my answer, please test again and, if this answer resolve your question, please mark it as correct ✔. This help others to find eassier the answer and help me to grow :)

Comment: Thank you so much. Of course, I have marked as best answer. Thanks again.